# PHP if statement variable has a value

Tags: php

Hi I have some simple code but I can't get a a condition if it has a value or not.

```
$widgetcalc = ['widgetcalc'];



<?php
  if ($widgetcalc == 1) {
    require('includes/calculator.php');
}

?>
```

Basically I have a value in a database which is either 1 or 0. In this case I think 1 is = true if it actually exists but how do I get 'if the value is equal to 1 in the database?

Comment: use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya odly, it's still not working

Comment: where are you getting the variable value from ?

Comment: "which is either 1 or 0"  Not according to the code above. The variable is an array with a single string in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing between assignment operator `=` and comparison operator `==`. Use `==` instead of `=`, to compare the values. Also, you need to use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function, as you are declaring `$widgetcalc` as an array.

It is even better to use **Identical comparison** operator `===`. It will ensure that the datatype of the values also match, besides matching the value

Reference: [Comparison Operators (PHP Doc)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
if (count($widgetcalc) == 1) {
```

OR

```
if (count($widgetcalc) === 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of programming languages `=` is *assignment* and `==` is *comparison*.

Learn to spot the difference, and to develop a keen sense of when `=` shows up inside an `if` statement as to if that's the correct intent.

If you're only concerned about 1 vs. 0 the safe version is:

```
if ($widgetcalc)
```

Where that's usually good enough unless you need *literally zero*.

In your code, though, you're checking if the array has *any elements*, which is different:

```
if (count($widgetcalc))
```

Where that employs the [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

first you can try this `if ($widgetcalc == 1)` instead of `if ($widgetcalc = 1)` also you can check `isset()` function which returns bool value. `if(isset($widgetcalc['widgetcalc'])){ //code here }`